# ¿Cómo decir "book authored by X" en español?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término, inglés

En ingles uno puede decir algo como:

> In the book **authored** by me, I explore ...

¿Cómo decir algo equivalente en español? ¿Existe un verbo que equivalga a "to author"?

En general es común decir cosas como "En el libro que yo escribí", pero no tiene la misma fuerza que "authored". ¿Sugerencias?

Comment: Duda, en inglés **authored** tiene implicaciones diferentes a "**write**"?

Comment: @alvalongo Si. Es más general. Incluye todo tipo de creación. Ver [acá](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/author#Verb).

Answer (score 4):

Para expresar:

- In the book **authored by me**, ...

en español, se puede decir:

- En el libro **de mi autoría**, ...

o

- En el libro **del cual soy autor**, ...